# Convergence in Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In Hilbert space $H$ we know that $||x_n|| \to 3, ||y_n|| \to 4$ and $||x_n+y_n||\to \sqrt{50}$ as $n\to \infty$. Prove convergence of $||x_n-y_n||$.

Since $H$ is Hilbert space, may we use parallelogram law to just compute that $||x_n-y_n||=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, with

$||x_n-y_n||^2+||x_n+y_n||^2=2||x_n||^2+2||y_n||^2$

we get $||x_n-y_n|| \to 0$ and not $||x_n-y_n||=0$.

Comment: There should be $2||y_n||$ instead of $ 4||y_n||$, I guess.

Comment: Ooops ! you are right ! An edit will follow. Thanks